# Unrecognized datatype for attribute "User.role"

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am Facing this Issue Using Enum Datatype with ORM and Database is mysql. anyone Expert tell what's wrong on below code. I'm trying to create a table but i keep getting Error:

**i am facing this below error. when i start server**

Error: 'Unrecognized datatype for attribute "User.role"'

**here is code:**"

```
 
        },
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM("user", "admin", "developer"),
            allowNull: false,
          },
```